# Does Ubuntu support the ASUS trackpad of a ZenBook-14-UX?

Tags: touchpad, asus, hardware

I am thinking about buying the [ASUS ZenBook 14](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-ZenBook-14-UX433FN/). It features a fancy kind of trackpad, which has extra virtual buttons integrated into it.

I am thinking about installing the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on it.
Do you know if Ubuntu supports this hardware?
How can I find out about this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Comment: @Pilot6 It's possibly a duplicate question, but this question has valuable unique answers so I voted to leave it open anyway.

Comment: @karel I agree that there are some useful answers. But IMHO AU is not a place to ask this type of questions. I am using this kind of laptops too and I asked this question before :) I took some part in discovering how to enable this feature in a bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: Unfortunately, as [a fellow user](https://askubuntu.com/users/731540/ldrahnik) suggested, you will need an [additional driver](https://github.com/asus-linux-drivers/asus-touchpad-numpad-driver) for the numpad on the touchpad to work.**

I believe their trackpad is just a fancy way of enabling NumLock, so if it doesn't need any extra driver, (is plug-n-play), the trackpad shouldn't be a problem.

However, you may need to install Nvidia drivers.

If you want to make sure it is compatible you should delve into reviews and technical documentation. I would personally check if it's plug n play or if it requires extra software, as soon as it requires extra software, it will be incompatible with other OS.

Answer (score 2):

Integrated numpad to touchpad is, unfortunately, still not working on Ubuntu 20.04 by default. ([reported issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1810183))

But I'm a developer and I've written [a linux driver that enables most of the features](https://github.com/asus-linux-drivers/asus-touchpad-numpad-driver). Download and configure for your device and it should work perfectly.